# VLC streamng from RTSP to HTML5

Tags: vlc, rtsp

I got RTSP stream from camera:

`rtsp://666666:666666@178.235.206.163:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0`

and VLC recognizes it (CTRL+N -> Paste -> it shows).

Now I want to stream into FLV (or to HTML5 OGG) using VLC.
Trying this command line:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" rtsp://666666:666666@178.235.206.163:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=FLV1,vb=2048,fps=25,scale=1,acodec=none,deinterlace}:http{mime=video/x-flv,mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=127.0.0.1:8090/device_1.flv}' :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=5 -sout-keep -no-audio -video -no-sout-audio
```

and now VLC doesn't recognize stream adress:

```
VLC could not connect to "666666:554". Input stream cannot be opened
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: Second version of command line: `"c:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -I dummy -vvv rtsp://666666:666666@178.235.206.163:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0 --sout "#standard{access=http,dst=:8080/output.mp4}"` and this time I got window with log, but also with errors. Run this as command to recreate (it'll be easier tsn putting this all here).

Answer (score 0):

Quote the RTSP address and use the proper format for parameters:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "rtsp://user:password@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0" --sout '#transcode{vcodec=FLV1,vb=2048,fps=25,scale=1,acodec=none,deinterlace}:http{mime=video/x-flv,mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=127.0.0.1:8090/device_1.flv}' --no-sout-standard-sap --ttl 5 --sout-keep --no-audio --video --no-sout-audio
```

*I didn't check your parameters, I just corrected the format*. 
There is an output and I can play the resulting FLV.

You might want to change your password.